# PHP IF inside <tr> <td> loop while looping results from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I would need to display results in 3 rows and have same values under each other. Currently results are all going under each other. My code would have 3 IF sentences inside the loop.

My code is here:

```
echo "
<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" align=\"center\" class=\"data\">
          <tr>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\"><h2>Vapaa</h2></td>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\"><h2>Varattu</h2></td>
            <td class=\"dataHeader\"><h2>Käyttö estetty</h2></td>
          </tr>
";
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

       echo "<tr>

            if ($result[tila] == 'vapaa') {

           <td>" . $result['id'] . " " . $result['tila']. "</td>

            }

            </tr>";

        }

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You forget to close your string before the if() statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want the if to be as text. So you have to do like this:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

      echo "<tr> ";

      //First if
      if ($result[tila] == 'vapaa') {
            echo "<td>" . $result['id'] . " " . $result['tila']. "</td>";
      } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
      }

      //Second if
      if ($result[tila] == 'varattu') { 
            echo '<td>' , $result['id'] , ' ' , $result['tila']. '</td>';             
      } else {
            echo '<td></td>';
      }

      // Here you can add more ifs.

      echo  "</tr>";
  }
```

Because tables need to have the same number of cells (`<td>`) in a you need to add empty `<td>`s as describe above.

Comment: How about if i want to add more IF sentences inside the loop? Because when i tried it values went under each other except when they were all the same. This is what i'm looking for: if ($result[tila] == 'vapaa') { echo '<td>' , $result['id'] , ' ' , $result['tila']. '</td>'; } if ($result[tila] == 'varattu') { echo '<td>' , $result['id'] , ' ' , $result['tila']. '</td>'; }

Comment: @OskarLehtonen I updated my answer with the second if you suggested. After that you can add more ifs.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but i still didn't get it to work the way i wanted. I will link a picture of my screen so you can see what's happening: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4diipza3gb2f6f/Screenshot%202016-05-23%2018.31.16.png?dl=0                                                                                Where should i add else {
       echo '<td></td>';
 } ?

Comment: @OskarLehtonen I updated my answer with `else` statement. This should work for you. Do the same with the 3rd column.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! One more thing that bothers me is that they start from different spots. Could this be modified some way? https://www.dropbox.com/s/stx52cpugrkcftq/Screenshot%202016-05-23%2018.47.02.png?dl=0

Comment: I don't get what you want to change now. Can you explain more?

Comment: I want to get rid of those empty spaces that are marked in the picture with red border. https://www.dropbox.com/s/io8ruk53ojp9p1o/Screenshot%202016-05-23%2018.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Wrong use of string quote delimiters.

```
echo '<table>';
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    if ($result[tila] == 'vapaa') {
        echo '<td>' , $result['id'] , ' ' , $result['tila']. '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```